# How to get a Module by its name in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

How to get `java.lang.Module` by string name in Java 9?

For example, we have

```
String name = "some.module";
Module module = //how to get here it?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to get your module from the boot layer which consists at least `java.base` after its initialization is:

```
String moduleName = "my.module";
Module m = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(moduleName).orElse(null);
```

though preferably a safe way IMO, would be to get a module would be using the `Configuration` and the system `ClassLoader` to get the [`ModuleLayer`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) of your module and then `findModule` as :

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/your/module");

ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(path);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();

Configuration configuration = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of(moduleName));
ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, systemClassLoader);
Module m = layer.findModule(moduleName).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Do I understand right - once created layer can not be modified? I mean it is not possible to add or remove module to/from it?

Comment: @Pavel_K a layer once created can be modified with the updates in the modules info included in it, if that's what you're asking. It's possible to remove/add a module to the layer if you're updating the module-info of your.module.

Comment: I mean the following - I have modules A and B and I create layer with these two module. Can I later 1) add new module to this layer? 2) remove module A from this layer? 3) update module A in this layer?

Comment: @Pavel_K Yes the layer would be modified with updates to the configuration as you do any of those actions.

Comment: I have seen this sort of method promoted in several places. However, it seems to require hard-coding the module path in the source code, which defeats the purpose of having a classpath (or module path in Java 9), which allows you to change which jar (or module) you depend upon when you launch the JRE. How is your second method better than your first method? (The second method is really an example of dynamic loading of modules.) Also, I think your first method won't work if there are multiple layers of modules?