# How to load JDK module programmatically?

Tags: java, java-module

Suppose we have module `A` that dynamically loads module `B` (using classes `ModuleFinder`, `ModuleLayer`, etc). Last one requires standard module `java.sql` that is not loaded into boot layer with module `A`. How to load required `java.sql` from JDK (or JRE) using java code?

**EDIT**

This sample maven project demonstrates my problem:

Project structure:

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───loader
│   │   pom.xml
│   │
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   ├───java
│       │   │   │   module-info.java
│       │   │   │
│       │   │   └───app
│       │   │       └───module
│       │   │           └───loader
│       │   │                   AppLoader.java
│       │   │                   AppModule.java
│       │   │
│       │   └───resources
│       └───test
│           └───java
└───sql-module
    │   pom.xml
    │
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   │   │   module-info.java
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───app
        │   │       └───module
        │   │           └───sql
        │   │                   SQLAppModule.java
        │   │
        │   └───resources
        └───test
            └───java
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sample-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>sample-app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>loader</artifactId>
</project>
```

loader/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sample-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>sample-app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>loader</artifactId>
</project>
```

loader/src/main/java/module-info.java:

```
module app.module.loader {
    exports app.module.loader;
    uses AppModule;
}
```

loader/src/main/java/app/module/loader/AppLoader.java:

```
public class AppLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var path = Paths.get("sql-module", "target", "classes");
        var moduleFinder = ModuleFinder.of(path);
        var boot = ModuleLayer.boot();
        var config = boot.configuration().resolveAndBind(moduleFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), Collections.emptyList());
        var newLayer = boot.defineModulesWithOneLoader(config, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        var testModule = ServiceLoader.load(newLayer, AppModule.class)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Module not found!"));
        System.out.println("Module name: " + testModule.name());
        System.out.println("Module version: " + testModule.version());
    }
}
```

loader/src/main/java/app/module/loader/AppModule.java:

```
public interface AppModule {
    String name();
    String version();
}
```

sql-module/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sample-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>sample-app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>sql-module</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sample-app</groupId>
            <artifactId>loader</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

sql-module/src/main/java/module-info.java:

```
module app.module.sql {
    requires app.module.loader;
    requires java.sql;

    provides AppModule with SQLAppModule;
}
```

sql-module/src/main/java/app/module/sql/SQLAppModule.java:

```
public class SQLAppModule implements AppModule {
    public SQLAppModule() {
        List<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.drivers().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Drivers on class path: " + drivers.size());
        drivers.forEach(d -> {
            System.out.println("Driver: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println("Version: " + d.getMajorVersion() + "." + d.getMinorVersion());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "SQL Module";
    }

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return "1.0-SNAPSHOT";
    }
}
```

When you try to launch application using main in `AppLauncher`, you will get an error (I use jdk-10.0.1 now):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.sql not found, required by app.module.sql
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.bind(Resolver.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:482)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:288)
    at app.module.loader/app.module.loader.AppLoader.main(AppLoader.java:14)
```

*What about hacks:* I think they must be used in the last place, so we try to find more or less "official" way to do it now.

*[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287690/2773647)* does not solve this problem, because `layer.findModule(moduleName).orElse(null)` on boot or any other layer will return null.

Comment: google shows this [snippet on gist](https://gist.github.com/rkx-bloodshed/badc6d0798b145123897a68ae4e3d6bd) but it looks a hack

Comment: Sorry. Hacked solutions are called like that for a reason. They are typically hard to understand and very often not very robust. A hack is your last resort, as a professional, you avoid them where possible.

Comment: The snippet on gist is indeed a hack because it's breaking into JDK internal APIs (invoking non-visible method with `setAccessible(true)`).  The entire point of Java Modules is to block code like this from working.  It works _for now_ in JDK 9/10 because `--illegal-access=permit` is the default option, but at some point in the future (JDK 11 or later) this approach will stop working.

Comment: Seems more like you're [looking to find a module by its name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287644/how-to-get-a-module-by-its-name-in-java-9)

Comment: @
IMustBeSomeone
 I think you're not understanding the correct use of the work hack in programming, a hack is a poor solution, a work around, because a refined solution cannot be found. Hacks are undesirable, as they are generally not reusable and modular.

Comment: Edited qestion to show problem with sample project

Comment: Containers need to launched with `--add-modules ALL-SYSTEM` so that all modules in the run-time image are in the boot layer. I any case, the issue with your code fragment is that you've specified the afterFinder parameter to be the empty module finder; if you had specified ModuleFinder.ofSystem() instead then it would have located modules in the run-time image that are in the boot layer. This will work for modules that don't have java.* packages.

Comment: @AlanBateman adding all modules from runtime image will break app when it uses artifacts conflicting with app dependencies (e.g., `java.xml.ws.annotation` and `javax.annotation-api`), but adding required modules using `--add-modules <concrete-modules>` will do work, and I dont know why to use `ModuleFinder.ofSystem()` (It seems to me that second module finder is useless at all, it is enaugh to include modules to first finder)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot and should not do that at runtime.

It is possible to get the missing modules that are required by your "app.module.sql" module:

```java
var missingModuleNames = moduleFinder.find("app.module.sql")
                                     .map(ModuleReference::descriptor)
                                     .map(ModuleDescriptor::requires)
                                     .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(ModuleDescriptor.Requires::name)
                                     .filter(name -> boot.findModule(name).isEmpty())
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And you can even create a `ModuleFinder` for the Java Platform Modules:

```java
var platformModules = Files.list(Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/modules")))
                           .collect(Collectors
                               .toMap(AppLoader::getModuleName, Function.identity()));

var missingModulePaths = missingModules.stream()
                                       .filter(systemModules::containsKey)
                                       .map(systemModules::get)
                                       .toArray(Path[]::new);

var missingModuleFinder = ModuleFinder.of(missingModulePaths);
```

But even if you do this recursive (`java.sql` requires `java.transaction.xa`), your attempt to load any of the platform modules will fail with a `LayerInstantiationException` as soon as you try to define the modules:

```java
var cfg = boot.configuration()
              .resolveAndBind(missingModuleFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), missingModules);

// This will throw the exception, because 'a layer cannot be created if the 
// configuration contains a module named "java.base", or a module contains a 
// package named "java" or a package with a name starting with "java.".'
// (see Javadoc of ModuleLayer#defineModulesWithOneLoader(Configuration, List<ModuleLayer>, ClassLoader)
ModuleLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cfg, List.of(boot), null);
```