# Is there a better way to load JDK modules dynamically than using `--add-modules ALL-SYSTEM`?

Tags: java, java-module

I am facing a similar situation as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776796/how-to-load-jdk-module-programmatically), which includes a demonstrating example of the problem that occurs when trying to dynamically load a Java 9-modularized jar, which depends on a JDK module that is not loaded by default. Since I cannot phrase it any better, here is an excerpt of the main idea:

> Suppose we have module `A` that dynamically loads module `B` (using classes `ModuleFinder`, `ModuleLayer`, etc). Last one requires standard module `java.sql` that is not loaded into boot layer with module `A`. How to load required `java.sql` from JDK (or JRE) using java code?

Specifically, my plugin (module `B` in the generic scenario) tries to create a connection to a Mysql database. On its own, it work as expected, but when I initially tried to use it in the framework  (module `A` in the generic scenario) , it failed for the same reason as in the linked topic:

`java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.sql not found, required by app.module.sql`

If my understanding is correct, there is no way to load modules from JDK on runtime (unlike third party modules). Therefore, the two option I found are:

1. Have the framework already depend on `java.sql` so that is will be loaded explicitly
2. Use `--add-modules ALL-SYSTEM`, which I prefer for not failing for other JDK modules in the future. However, I read that this has a drawback of loading too many modules, potentially two modules with the same name causing trouble.

However, this does not solve everything: For some reason, the automatic loading of the mysql database driver hidden behind the `DriverManager.getConnection` method, also does not work. I need to explicitly call `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` beforehand.

So I wonder, if there is a better way by now (the post is four years old) or if the option two is fine for what it's worth.

Comment: Either `Thread.setContextClassLoader` or `ServiceLoader.load(moduleLayer, javax.sql.Driver.class).forEach(d -> {})` may help.